# java: save and retrieve objects as objects rather than text information?

Tags: java

I have a program that actually stores inputted data into an array. These data will then be displayed through a text file from the array. I was asked to modify these program so that it is saving and retrieving objects as objects rather than a text information and i don't really know how to do that.. Need some advice thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the very simple XStream library as documented per their "[two minute tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)".